# property of undefined (reading 'push') in inheritance method javascript class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, inheritance

I would like to create an array of names containing all names the child has ever had, including the name it is defaulted with.

But when I try to run the code, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`.

```
class Child {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.names = new Array(name);
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  get names() {
    return this._names;
  }
  set name(newName) {
    this._name = newName
  }

  set names(newName) {
    this.names.push(newName)
  }
}

class Girl extends Child {
  constructor(name = "Sally") {
    super(name);
  }
}

class Boy extends Child {
  constructor(name = "Joe") {
    super(name);
  }
}

const child = new Child();
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? Sorry, I am new to OOP and JavaScript and I can't for the life of me seem to find an explanation for what is happening.

Comment: Because `this._names` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with inheritance, the problem is the constructor of the base class.

```
this.names = new Array(name)
```

uses the `set names` function. This pushes onto `this._names`, but that property has never been created.

The constructor needs to assign the internal `_names` property so there will be an array for the setter to push onto. So change that line to:

```
this._names = [name];
```

Comment: thank you, that makes so much sense! I think what confused me was what was actually being called in the set function. I didnt know I was accessing the property. thank you